# SignalR .Net 2.4.1-Dead Connection Id Staying Alive

Tags: signalr

I'm witnessing an odd behavior with my SignalR client (Android). OnDisconnected event is firing, the connection becomes dead, but my hub aborts the event and reissues the connection id as a new connection:

[image]

This seems to occur when the Android client goes into a slow state. It's messing up my status indicator on my UI showing that the user is still connected, yet they have logged out. What's the best approach to handle this situation? Should I stop my hub and reconnect when my connection is slow? I thought about getting the connection id from the hub but there's no way to indicate whether or not the connection is alive or dead.

Comment: Are you using the Java client or JS client?  If Java, please be aware that the SignalR Java client is no longer maintained. https://github.com/SignalR/java-client#this-repository-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-used-or-maintained.  It JS, there is a connection but that has been fixed for Chrome in v2.4.2.

Comment: Do you have any backplanes for your server if you are using more than one?

Comment: @eglease I'm not using a load balancer. Single server on Azure. I'm using the Java client but I can't upgrade to the newer signal. Believe me, I would love to!! :)

Comment: are you able to change or edit the Java client?

Comment: It may help to see your client and hub source code.  Are you able to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation (using .NET client) and ended up having to implement a heartbeat hub where a simple message (heartbeat) is sent to each client every 15 seconds.  The clients have a timer that listens to the heartbeat and resets when it gets a new one.

If two heartbeats are missed, the client closes the connection, waits a few seconds, and opens a new one.  There is no way to close a connection from the server.  This should allow the server to get the close connection message from the client and actually kill the connection.

Please be aware that the SignalR Java client is no longer maintained. https://github.com/SignalR/java-client#this-repository-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-used-or-maintained.